# Performance (early completion) of multiple workflow items

Tags: 2013, workflow

I've tried the various `stsadm` tuning options but find that if a few hundred documents get posted, each setting off my fairly complex workflow (which includes about 100 steps, including create and update of list items and moving the document to one of a few libraries but nothing huge), the whole thing grinds to a halt on our 16Gb RAM WFE.

Posting them, say, 50 at a time, seems to be much more efficient as it pretty much runs each of the 50 to completion fairly quickly, rather than trying to run all of the hundreds of workflows at once in parallel, jumping around trying to complete a small part, then moving on to the next one. This takes forever.

Are there any options other than a hardware solution. If there was some way of saying something like `"pause commencement until <51 workflows are running"`, this would seem to be the answer. I can't get my head around how to set the tuning options to make the earlier workflow tasks complete as quickly as possible.